# MVC Action Link in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, actionlink

I'm new to MVC, trying to work out how `@Html.ActionLink`s work in partial views.

Background- here's the relevant portion of the solution

```
Models
  PersonViewModel.cs
Views
  Addresses
    AddressListPartial.cshmtl
  Person
    Details.cshtml
```

I created a PersonViewModel, which has `FirstName`, `LastName` and List of `Address`es. I created a partial view using the List scaffold for the Address table, and added the following to my view for the Person to show the list of address on the `Person/Details` page:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Address/AddressListPartial.cshtml", Model.Addresses)
```

This is correctly showing the AddressList on the page, however, the "Create", "Edit", etc links on the AddressList are linking to `Views/Person/Edit/{id}` instead of to `Views/Address/Edit/{id}`.

Partial view action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AddressID }) |
```

So, the partial view is inheriting the `ActionLink` folder of the `Person` instead of the `Address`. Is there a way to make these ActionLinks in the partial view refer to the Address folder/controller instead of Person?

I tried this, but if the partial view is somewhere other than in a subfolder in the Views folder, this won't work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "../Address/Edit", new { id=item.AddressID }) |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you load the page, are you loading a `Person` from the `PersonsController` perhaps?  I don't think the `ActionLink` really cares what partial view it's in, but rather what controller action rendered the view.  And the default convention for resolving the URL when rendering the page would go back to that same controller.

You can override that default and explicitly specify a controller using one of the overloads for `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Address", new { id = item.AddressID }, null)
```

(Note that there's also an extra `null` parameter on the end.  That particular overload also includes an object for HTML attributes.  You're not using those, but [there's no overload of this kind without it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) so you can just pass `null` to it.)